# Understnding postion parameter in getView method of simplecursoradapter android

Tags: android

I would like to understand in detail the significance of position parameter in getView method of adapter.In a ListView i would like to set custom adapter with Textview and button.
The code is mentioned below.

```
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {  
        try
        {
            if(convertView==null)
            {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();   
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactslist, null);

             name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactname);
            number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactmobnum);
             call=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.callcust);
            }
            name.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            number.setText(cursor.getString(2));
            cursor.moveToNext();
            call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                                            Log.i("Testing","Position selected is "+position);
                                          }             
                                    });

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("Testing", "isDefault::: exec"+e);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

If suppose i have total 10 items in the cursor and i click on 5th position call button,what is the expected result?
Will it be 10 or 5?
Am confused because i used Base Adapter earlier and have experienced it as 10 but in the above code it returns 5,Please let me understand if the position returns the row id only while row is added in list or it also returns you the selected row id?
Looking forward for better understanding

Comment: Post the class that contain your convertView.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the 5th position call button then the position would be 4. The position is a zero base index of the row in the list. Just log the position in the getView and click a row and you will see.

Comment: I am not speaking about list item ,i am talking about call button on click  placed inside list adapter as mentioned in above code.

Comment: The position does not refer to the button, it refers to the row. If you want to know in which row the button is clicked you have to save the row index in the button tag.

Comment: If i have not specified any tag and just print position inside onclick listener of button mentioned in adapter it normally returns the last position but in above code it returns the clicked row id,so am confused

Comment: The position variable suppose not to exist in your onClickListener, it could be anything when you click. Show me your convertview class and I will show you how to set the tag for the button.

Comment: I am not trying to set a seperate onclick listener,trying to place onclick listener inside getView method of adapter

Comment: You can set onClickListener many different way, but they all amount to the same thing. The anonymous class is one way. getView would not be called when you click your button. So position can be anything in memory. It is just by coincidence you get the value 10 and now 5. If you scroll around and click the same button again, I would bet you will get different number.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 10 items, you will must return 10 on the getCount() method.

The method getView() will be called ten times to populate the listView when you set the adapter of the listView or when you call to notifyDatasetChanged().

You can use the OnItemClickListener of the listView to get the clicked item. In the case of click the 5 item, the position on the listener will be the 4 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4...).

Comment: I am not speaking about list item ,i am talking about call button on click placed inside list adapter as mentioned in above code,need what will this Log print .